# (jQuery) Toggle div style "display:none" to "display:inline"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 divs which and I want to be able to toggle between them onClick of a button (currently using .toggle();)

The div that shows on the page is div1. This div has the style 'display:inline'.
My other div (div2) starts with the style 'display:none'.

When the div1 switches to div2, I want div2 to have the style of "display:inline". How do I do this?

EDIT: This is working:

```
$(function(){
  $('#button').click(function(){

    $('#div1').toggleClass('hide');

if ($('#div2').is('.hidden')) {

          $('#div2').removeClass('hidden');
          $('#div2').addClass('show');


      }
      else{

          $('#div2').addClass('hidden');
          $('#div2').removeClass('show');


      }


  });
});
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I would use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) as toggle switches between `display: inline;` and `display: block;`

Create a hidden and inline class and just toggle those.

Comment: I'm trying this but div2 doesn't show. I updated the code in my question.

Comment: My mistake, the script I'm using in the question is working! Forgot to clear cache :) Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Using plain JavaScript, you could use:

```
document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'inline';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do it:

1. For the html, we have a simple button to call the "toggleFunction" that will add and remove display classes to our Div elements as necessary.

   `<button onclick="toggleFunction()" >Click to toggle</button>`

   `<div id="div1" class="  "  > Now showing "Div 1" </div>`

   `<div id="div2" class="  "  > Now showing "Div 2" </div>`
2. We'll set the default display properties of **Div 1** and **Div 2** to "inline" and "none" respectively, so that by default:

   - **Div 1** is Shown, and
   - **Div 2** is Hidden.

Here is the css for that:

```
#div1 {
    display: inline;
    color:blue;
}

#div2 {
    display: none;
    color:red;
}

.display-none {
    display: none !important;
}

.display-inline {
    display: inline !important;
}
```

3. Finally, we'll use Jquery to add and remove the "display-none" and the "display-inline" classes to Div 1 and Div 2 respectively by calling our "toggleFunction" when the button is clicked.

Here is the Jquery for that:

```
  function toggleFunction() {
    $("#div1").toggleClass("display-none");    
    $("#div2").toggleClass("display-inline");    
  }
```

You can try it out on codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEbXwG

Answer (score 0):

Make your own `if` clause to toggle the div's style:

```js
$(document).on("click","#mybutton",function(){
  var toggled=$("#mydiv");
  
  // instead of this which would make a block appear
  // toggled.toggle();
  
  // do this: create your own toggle if clause.
  if(toggled.is(":visible"))
    toggled[0].style.display="none";
  else
    toggled[0].style.display="inline";
});
```

```css
#mydiv{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mydiv">hello</div>
<button id="mybutton">toggle</button>
```